# Xcode 12 In App Purchase Implementation - SKProductsRequestDelegate does not get called

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to understand implementing IAP using Xcode 12 and SwiftUI. I prepared everything using App Store Connect and also registered the product id.

I'm using a StoreManager class adapting the SKProductsRequestDelegate protocol to fetch the corresponding SKProduct of the specified product id.

However, the func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) never gets called even when I'm working with a physical device. Actually, the console prints nothing at all.

I don't understand why this function never gets called.

```
class StoreManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

override init() {
    super.init()
    getProducts()
}

func getProducts() {
    let productID = "com.dev8882.MyDungeon.IAP.PowerSword"
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set([productID]))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Did receive response")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My code is a bit different. It's been about 3 years, so I'm not able to be as detailed in my explanation of *why* this works, but basically I'm creating my product ID(s) as an `NSSet`, then force-casting it as a `Set` of `Strings`:

```
let productID = NSSet(objects: "com.dev8882.MyDungeon.IAP.PowerSword")
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this fixed my problem:

According the Apple docs a strong reference SKProductsRequest should by used to start the request. So I updated my code like this:

class StoreManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

```
var request: SKProductsRequest!

override init() {
    super.init()
    request = SKProductsRequest()
    self.getProducts()
}

func getProducts() {
    print("OK")
    let productID = "com.dev8882.MyDungeon.IAP.PowerSword"
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set([productID]))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Did receive response")
}
```

}

It works fine now.